# IValueConverter not working in VS2012-Blend for win 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, windows-phone-8

I'm using VS 2012 and Blend for windows 8. When I use to use Converters in my Windows Phone and Silverlight apps I would click on new convert and picked my converter from the list.  Now that I have upgraded to VS 2012 and Blend for windows 8 none of my custom converts are showing up.  Anyone know how to find the converters?

```
 class Class1 : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, they work for me in WP8. Are you sure you got a reference to System.Windows.Data in your project?

Comment: Yes its there. Its just a simple new project for wp8 then I add a converter and then try to bind for it using show all. Nothing I create will show up. I know it works for windows 8 apps, but not working for wp8... VS2012 and Blend won't show them. its just odd.

Comment: Could you post a little more of your code? Your .xaml page for example?

Comment: These are the steps. 1: create a new windows phone 8 app in vs2012 using windows 8. 2: add a class. 3: add the converter code and compile. 4: find a text box like the title on main page and click data context then bind. I look for converters and add a new one and click show all. For some reason mine doesn't show up but others do if I add the control toolkit. Even blend won't show them. Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

've never done it the way you posted in the comment (do you have a reference to your converter namespace?), however this works. Add a reference to your converter namespace ontop of your .xaml:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Appname.Views.Converters"
```

Then declare the converter:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converters:SavedTrackColorConverter x:Key="SavedTrackColorConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then use the converter where desired:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ListboxStringSavedTunes, Converter={StaticResource SavedTrackColorConverter}}" Text="{Binding ListboxStringSavedTunes}"/>
```

Comment: Blend always added everything, I'll try adding it manually but it seems odd that the software use to add the reference and now it doesn't?

Comment: Sadly you are right. VS 2012 and Blend for windows 8 no longer does the adding of the reference. I also noticed that when you embed a font you now have to do all the code by hand for windows store apps.  This is sad because these functions were part of vs 2010. Why would MS remove something that makes the developers work less? Maybe we should go back to notepad and forget VS.